Migrate ibatis choose cases to native SQL
I have the following ibatis query which I want to migrate from Oracle to PostgreSQL with Hibernate.
                   BEGIN
                      INSERT INTO users(
                          user_id,
                          personal_id,
                          created_by,
                          modified_by
                      ) VALUES (
                          #{user_id},
                          #{personal_id},
                          <choose>
                            <when test="userCred == true">'profile'</when>
                            <otherwise>'basic'</otherwise>
                          </choose>,
                          <choose>
                            <when test="userCred == true">'profile'</when>
                            <otherwise>'basic'</otherwise>
                          </choose>
                      );
                    EXCEPTION WHEN HIST_INDEX THEN
                        UPDATE ..........
                    END;    


void insert(@Param("user_id") long user_id, @Param("userCred") boolean userCred);

Do you know how I can migrate properly <choose> statements for PostgreSQL and also migrate Begin...Exception block for PostgreSQL?

You'll need to recode the ' ` as logic in the java app.

PostgreSQL does support begin...exception blocks in PL/pgSQL.

How I can migrate it?

Did you check the PostgreSQL documentation? There is not a "one size fits all" or "do this and you'll be fine". https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-porting.html
